# Javascript Animate Matching CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the Javascript animation to match exactly my css animation. I'm not sure why this is not working? I'm trying to use basic javascript. not jquery. The second div should be matching the animation of the first div

https://jsfiddle.net/JokerMartini/pf2nt4su/

```js
let content = document.getElementById("content");

html = `<div class="base"></div>`;
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
let div = doc.body.firstChild;

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API
// keyframes
var keyframes = [{
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  opacity: 0
}, {
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  opacity: 1
}];
// timing 
let timing = {
  duration: 2000,
  iterations: Infinity
}

div.animate([
  keyframes,
  timing
]);

//elements += html;
content.append(div)
```

```css
body {
  background: #808080;
}

.base {
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  background: black;
}

.sample {
  animation: play 2s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='base sample'></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: You have an error here: `opacity: 1;`, you should remove the `;`. I am not sure if it's related to your issue

Comment: no that is not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: Replace below (notice square brackets)

```
div.animate([
  keyframes,
  timing
]);
```

with:

```
document.getElementById("content").animate(
  keyframes,
  timing
);
```

Here working code snippet: (updated with steps in JS)

```html
<style>
body {
  background: #808080;
}

.base {
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  background: black;
}

.sample {
  animation: play 2s steps(8) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
</style>

<div class='base sample'></div> <br>
<div id="content" class="base"></div>
<script>
let content = document.getElementById("content");

html = `<div class="base"></div>`;
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
let div = doc.body.firstChild;

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API
// keyframes
var keyframes = [{
 backgroundColor: 'green',
  opacity: 0 
}, {
 backgroundColor: 'blue',
  opacity: 1
}];
// timing 
var timing = {
  duration: 2000,
   easing: 'steps(8)',
  iterations: Infinity
}



document.getElementById("content").animate(
  keyframes,
  timing
);



</script>
```

Comment: in the css im setting a 'steps' value. how do i do that in the javascript

Comment: yes you can do that as well. I will update the code now

Comment: @JokerMartini please check now

Answer (score 0):

Move the `content.append(div)` before the animate call. Also, remove the `[]` from the animate.

I forked your JSFiddle. Here is a working version. https://jsfiddle.net/jrgiant/c5z7x2bu/.

```js
let content = document.getElementById("content");

html = `<div class="base"></div>`;
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
let div = doc.body.firstChild;

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API
// keyframes
var keyframes = [{
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  opacity: 0
}, {
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  opacity: 1
}];
// timing 
let timing = {
  duration: 2000,
  iterations: Infinity
}
content.append(div)
div.animate(
  keyframes,
  timing
);

//elements += html;
```

```css
body {
  background: #808080;
}

.base {
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  background: black;
}

.sample {
  animation: play 2s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='base sample'></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: in the css im setting a 'steps' value. how do i do that in the javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your exact problem is that you are applying the animation before appending the div, and passing the `keyframes` argument as a list of lists instead of a list of objects (as you defined it):

```
let content = document.getElementById("content");

html = `<div class="base"></div>`;
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
let div = doc.body.firstChild;
content.append(div)


// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API
// keyframes
var keyframes = [{
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  opacity: 0
}, {
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  opacity: 1
}];
// timing 
let timing = {
  duration: 200,
  iterations: Infinity
}

div.animate(
  keyframes,
  timing
);
```

Comment: in the css im setting a 'steps' value. how do i do that in the javascript